# Set Children Properties with Custom Attribute in Parent Class

Tags: c#

I am creating a Log Parsing tool, that is parsing a CSV File into individual classes that derive from a root class. However, it is taking a long time to define the individual classes and to set their individual properties in each class, since there is hundreds of different types of logs. The thing I did notice is that it is all pretty much exactly the same thing and wanted to see if there was a way to speed things up and do something along the lines of how LINQ to DB does things and add some logic in to automatically set properties based on information from Attributes.

Below is an example of what I am working with and an idea on how things should work.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            {"key", "Stack Overflow"},
            {"item1", "Test"},
            {"item2", "Sample"},
            {"item3", "3"}
        };

        Example example = new Example(dictionary);
        Console.WriteLine(example.LogKey);  //Stack Overflow
        Console.WriteLine(example.Item1);   //Test
        Console.WriteLine(example.Item2);   //
        Console.WriteLine(example.Item3);   //3
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
class LogItem : Attribute
{
    public LogItem(string key)
    {
        Key = key;
    }

    public string Key { get; private set; }
    public bool Ignore { get; set; }
}

class Log
{
    public Log(Dictionary<string, string> items)
    {
        Dictionary = items;
    }

    public Dictionary<string, string> Dictionary { get; private set; }

    [LogItem("key")]
    public string LogKey { get; set; }
}

class Example : Log
{
    public Example(Dictionary<string, string> items) : base(items)
    {
    }

    [LogItem("item1")]
    public string Item1 { get; set; }

    [LogItem("item2", Ignore = true)]
    public string Item2 { get; set; }

    [LogItem("item3")]
    public int Item3 { get; set; }
}
```

All of my data is comming through as a string unfortunately so it would be a good idea to get the type of the property and converting the string to that. Not important right now for this question since I can do that on my own.

Does anyone have an idea on how to make something like this work? If possible could something like this be done in the Parent Class to allow the Child Class to set the properties with the Attribute `Ignore == true` on it's own.

Comment: You can use reflection to set properties, but if you already have `Dictionary`, why do you really need properties? What will be the usage of `Example` class? Why not keeping `Dictionary`? Moreover it's not really clear (to me?) of how is that related to attributes. CSV -> dictionary, perfect, no need for classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to come up with the following after looking into how LINQ to CSV works.

```
static void ExtractData(Log log)
{
    List<PropertyInfo> propertyInfos =
        log.GetType()
            .GetProperties()
            .Where(
                p => p.GetCustomAttributes(typeof (LogItem), true).Any(logItem => !((LogItem) logItem).Ignore))
            .ToList();

    foreach (var propertyInfo in propertyInfos)
    {
        LogItem logItem = (LogItem)propertyInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(LogItem), true).First();

        if(!log.Dictionary.ContainsKey(logItem.Key))
            continue;

        TypeConverter typeConverter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(propertyInfo.PropertyType);
        MethodInfo parseNumberMethod = propertyInfo.PropertyType.GetMethod("Parse",
            new[] { typeof(String), typeof(NumberStyles), typeof(IFormatProvider) });
        MethodInfo parseExactMethod = propertyInfo.PropertyType.GetMethod("ParseExact",
            new[] { typeof(string), typeof(string), typeof(IFormatProvider) });

        Object objValue = null;

        if (typeConverter.CanConvertFrom(typeof(string)))
        {
            objValue = typeConverter.ConvertFromString(null, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, log.Dictionary[logItem.Key]);
            Debug.WriteLine("TypeConverter - " + propertyInfo.Name);
        }
        else if (parseExactMethod != null)
        {
            objValue =
                parseExactMethod.Invoke(
                    propertyInfo.PropertyType,
                    new Object[]
                        {
                            log.Dictionary[logItem.Key],
                            logItem.OutputFormat,
                            CultureInfo.CurrentCulture
                        });
        }
        else if (parseNumberMethod != null)
        {
            objValue =
                parseNumberMethod.Invoke(
                    propertyInfo.PropertyType,
                    new Object[]
                        {
                            log.Dictionary[logItem.Key],
                            logItem.NumberStyles,
                            CultureInfo.CurrentCulture
                        });
        }
        else
        {
            objValue = log.Dictionary[logItem.Key];
        }

        PropertyInfo goodPropertyInfo = propertyInfo.DeclaringType.GetProperty(propertyInfo.Name);
        goodPropertyInfo.SetValue(log, objValue, null);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen LinqToCSV? You create classes for each of the types of log, adding inheritance etc and describe the columns using attributes.

here's an example of how simple your code would become.

```
IEnumerable<ManualInputFormat> MapFileToRows(Stream input)
{
    var csvDescriptor = new CsvFileDescription
                            {
                                SeparatorChar = ',',
                                FirstLineHasColumnNames = true
                            };

    var context = new CsvContext();
    return context.Read<InputFormat>(new StreamReader(input), csvDescriptor);
}
```

where InputFormat is your destination attribute decorated POCO

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25133/LINQ-to-CSV-library

Comment: OP wants CSV to something. And link only answer are not very welcomed (consider to post important key parts from there).

Comment: While I agree about link only answers. This page has been there for a fairly long time (2008) and I have used this solution many times in production. If the page ever gets removed there will probably be a better solution available and therefore this answer becomes obsolete.